# Why I can't get the param in the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help me with this,I want to show the data with the pagination,but in the Controller Method,I can't get the param.

I created a codepen,please see it on http://codepen.io/SmilePark/pen/vOVPXy

this is my view:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li ng-class="{true:'active'}[currentPage==1]"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="currentPage=1;load()">Home Page</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{true:'disabled'}[currentPage==1]"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="prev()">Prev</a></li>
            <li ng-repeat="page in pages"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="currentPage=page;load()">{{ page }}</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{true:'disabled'}[currentPage==totalPage]"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="next()">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{true:'active'}[currentPage==totalPage]"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="currentPage=totalPage;load()">Last Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and this is my controller:

```
userApp.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'serverUrl', function($scope, $http, serverUrl) {
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.currentCount = 3;
$scope.pages = [];

$http.get(serverUrl + "/users?page=" + $scope.currentPage + "&count=" + $scope.currentCount + "&mobile=&userId=0&status=1").success(function(data) {
    if (data.code == 0) {
        $scope.items = data.data.users;
        $scope.totalPage = Math.ceil(data.numTotal / $scope.currentCount);
        for(var i=1;i<$scope.totalPage+1;i++){
            $scope.pages.push(i);
        }
    }
})

$scope.searchData = function() {
    $scope.load();
}
$scope.load = function() {
    var userId = 0,
        mobile = "",
        startDate = "",
        endDate = "";
    if ($scope.userId != undefined) {
        userId = $scope.userId;
    }
    if ($scope.mobile != undefined) {
        mobile = $scope.mobile;
    }
    if ($scope.startDate != undefined) {
        startDate = new Date($scope.startDate).getTime();
    }
    if ($scope.endDate != undefined) {
        endDate = new Date($scope.endDate).getTime();
    }
    var url = serverUrl + "/users?page=" + $scope.currentPage + "&count=" + $scope.currentCount + "&mobile=" + mobile + "&userId=" + userId + "&startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate + "&status=1"
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        if (data.code == 0) {
            $scope.items = data.data.users;
        }
    })
}
$scope.loadLast = function(){
    $scope.currentPage = $scope.totalPage;
}

$scope.prev = function() {
    $scope.currentPage--;
    $scope.load();
}

$scope.next = function() {
    $scope.currentPage++;
    $scope.load();
}
```

When I click the 'Last Page',`$scope.currentPage` is 'NaN',what's wrong with this?

Comment: when at last page define current page to 1.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal sorry,I don't really understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I could not comment hence writing here) .. is your http request returning data.numTotal as value? otherwise I don't see any issue with your code.

Comment: Yes numTotal is 8,When I click the 'Last Page',the http request is :'http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/api/admin/users?page=NaN&count=3&mobile=&userId=0&startDate=&endDate=&status=1',   the 'page' is 'NaN'

Comment: While accessing users - you are using data.data.users, and for numTotal you using it directly data.numTotal … apart from data.numTotal I don't see any other issue, perhaps if you can create a CodePen with sample http response … I can try and fix this for you.

Comment: It is as I predicted - it should data.data.numTotal as numTotal is inside data attribute of the function argument data, hence the following should be the change - 
$scope.totalPage = Math.ceil(data.data.numTotal / $scope.currentCount);